SwiftUI toggle response to Notification Permissions denied
I'm triggering a request authorization for local notification permissions using a toggle in swiftUI, when the toggle is turned on, the user is requested for permission access, I want the toggle to turn back off when the 'don't allow' button is tapped, I've implemented my own way of doing it below by setting the Bool binding back to false and using the @Observable macro in iOS 17 to observe state changes but the view isn't observing the updated change and the toggle does not turn off.
Here's a shortened version of my implementation below, could anyone spot what I'm missing here?
Game class
@Observable
final class Game {

var appSettings: AppSettings

init() {
appSettings = AppSettings()
}

@Observable
final class AppSettings {

    var reminderEnabled: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(reminderEnabled, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.reminderEnabled)
        }
    }


init() {
reminderEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.reminderEnabled) as? Bool ?? false  
}

AppSettingsView
struct AppSettingsView: View {
    @Bindable var game: Game
    @Bindable var appSettings: AppSettings
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Toggle("Daily Reminder", isOn: $appSettings.reminderEnabled)
                        .onChange(of: appSettings.reminderEnabled) { newValue in
                            if newValue {
                                NotificationManager.shared.requestNotificationPermissions { granted in
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        if granted {
                                            NotificationManager.shared.scheduleNotification(at: appSettings.reminderTime)
                                        } else {
                                            appSettings.reminderEnabled = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                NotificationManager.shared.cancelNotification()
                            }
                        }

NotificationManager
final class NotificationManager {
    
    static let shared = NotificationManager()
    
    var deniedAlertShown:Bool = false
    
    private init() {}
    
    func requestNotificationPermissions( completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
            if success {
                completion(success)
            } else if let error {
                completion(success)
                print("error requesting permissions: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

  func cancelNotification() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    }


AppStorage but storing the user response in user defaults is pointless because they can turn it off at any time.

Are you saying to store the closure response in AppStorage and update the Bool with the AppStorage value?

One typo may be in your code in notiifcation manager in error part of the closure you have used completion(success) .

Yes, but as I mentioned before it is pointless just make the call when you need it.

Consider using the async/await version. Calling it in succession becomes much more intuitive. Completion handlers are the “old way” of coding with Swift. Swift6 is the way forward.

@loremipsum I switched to using async/await as per your suggestion and it worked.

Posted my solution below after the comment from @loremipsum

In iOS, if you already pressed "Don't Allow" with any permission. you'll no longer see it again. You have to allow it in the Setting by yourself.
The best way, you should check that permission is exist or not. If it doesn't have you should show something to navigate to the Setting.

Yes I know this, and plan to implement something similar  but my question was related to the toggle, I simply want to turn the toggle off based on the result returned from the request authorization closure, if denied, then switch the toggle state to off.

So I switched my approach from a completion handler to using async/await as per the suggestion from lorem ipsum and it did help me with my issue, I am able to change the toggle state now depending on the request authorization outcome. Note: this code is obviously not clean, as it'll always set the toggle to off now if denied in the onChange modifier, but that can be fixed separately, this answer is just posted for anyone else curious. Thanks everyone.
//NotificationManager
func requestNotificationPermissions()  async -> Bool {
    do {
        return  try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return false
}

//AppSettingsView
 Toggle("Daily Reminder", isOn: $appSettings.reminderEnabled)
                    .onChange(of: appSettings.reminderEnabled) { newValue in
                        if newValue {
                            Task {
                                let permissionsGranted = await NotificationManager.shared.requestNotificationPermissions()
                                if permissionsGranted {
                                    NotificationManager.shared.scheduleNotification(at: appSettings.reminderTime)
                                } else {
                                    appSettings.reminderEnabled = false 
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            NotificationManager.shared.cancelNotification()
                        }   


Awesome, the only thing I would change is onChange(of to .task(id those floating Task are not good practice

Oh I see, so .task(id: sort of works similarly to onChangeOf with id being the trigger, ok will give that a go, thank you!

Yup, glad to help

I agree with lorem ipsum, but keep in mind that task(id:) is also triggered upon creation of id.
